# "Muss man dabei gewesen sein" in English

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, translation

German has an idiom,

> (Da) muss man dabei gewesen sein

I'd say it means

> You cannot understand the emotion/memory if you weren't present when it happened.

I couldn't find an equivalent English idiom, so I'm counting on your knowledge.

Comment: I don't think that it is an idiom - it seems understandable literally. It is very similar to the English - "[But, really,] you would had to have been there." /  "[But, really,] you had to be there."

Comment: Maybe I didn't find the right term. But I think the expression qualifies as idiomatic, at least colloquially in the younger generation.

Comment: There is a difference between 1. "an idiom" (noun) e.g. "Keep your hair on" = "Stop being angry" and 2. something that is "idiomatic" (adj.) =  considered to be natural.

Answer (score 9):

The English saying is

> You had to be there!

Comment: I'd agree that that's the equivalent, Colin, but it's comparatively new as an idiom, I don't remember it from any earlier than the 80s at least. I wonder if it's a translation into English of the German original.

Comment: Google Ngrams shows small peaks around 1880 and 1915, and a steady rise since 1960. This is for the whole phrase. Not all the uses will be an exlamation.

Comment: Do the Ngrams show those peaks and small rise in British English or only in US English? I ask because some Americanisms are translations of German terms and phrases (a good example is "hopefully") and "You had to be there" seems like an Americanism to me.

Comment: @BoldBen, the pattern for English and for American English is very similar, except that the bump around 1915 is larger for English. Since British English shows nothing till 1910, and the graph is more angular, which I take it implies that the total number of instances is rather lower.

Comment: It might well be that the German idiom is not older than the English one.

Comment: @BoldBen Do you have a source for the statement that *hopefully* is a translation from German? Wiktionary suggests it's a native English construction (hope + ful + ly). And more importantly, German *hoffnungsvoll* means "full of hope". To convey "it is hoped that", you'd use *hoffentlich*. A closer English parallel to *hoffentlich* would be *hopely or *hopedly.

Comment: I agree, @Cacambo. I think it is possible (though far from inevitable) that the _use_ of "hopefully" as a sentence adverb is calqued from German "hoffentlich"; but the _word_ certainly isn't.

Comment: @ColinFine That's really what I meant but I didn't express it well. Obviously "hopefully" as in "It is better to travel hopefully than to arrive" is a native English word. It's the use of "Hopefully we will arrive in time" which is a comparatively recent structure and seems to be derived from German.

Comment: @BoldBen Thank you for the explanation. I generally don't have such deep insight into the English language.